# MySQL creating a table

Tags: mysql, database

I am brand new playing with MySQL, I got a really tricky error when I delete "users" table and rebuild it again. The reason why I delete it is :when I type "SELECT * FROM users" before,it shows the table "users" doesn't exist,but actually it really showed on the table list of the current database.
    enter code here

```
    mysql> create table users(
           -> name VARCHAR(50),
           -> password VARCHAR(50),
           -> email VARCHAR(50),
           -> online INT,
           -> ip VARCHAR(50));
    ERROR 1813 (HY000): Tablespace for table '`smartfsusers`.`users`' exists. Please   DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
    mysql> select * from users;
    ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'smartfsusers.users' doesn't exist
```

Comment: did you google "error 1146"? you may find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when a database is corrupt or an import was interrupted. However, what's happening here is that

1. there's a `users.ibd` file (which means there is a users table in the innodb tablespace)
2. there's no `users.frm` (which means there's no users table in the information schema).

If you're running locally, one way to go is manually deleting users.ibd somewhere inside /var/lib/mysql. This will only work if you're running with the option file-per-table enabled.

You can also try doing this from the command prompt

```
ALTER TABLE smartsurfers.users DISCARD TABLESPACE
```

You could also try stopping mysqld and running mysqlcheck

```
mysqlcheck -u youruser -p smartsurfers
```